# Selenium selecting an element and clicking the button using python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Copy of element via inspect:

```
</span></div></div></div><button class="primary LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton SimpleButton_root ButtonOverrides_root" label="Continue">Continue</button></div>
```

I am trying to press the continue button to go to the. next page

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[(@class='primary LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton SimpleButton_root ButtonOverrides_root')
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[(@class='primary LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton SimpleButton_root ButtonOverrides_root')]"}
```

also:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("primary LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton SimpleButton_root ButtonOverrides_root")
```

Resulting in again `NoSuchElementException`

Anyone have a tip ?

Comment: Try this: `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Continue"]')` or `"//button[@class='primary LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton SimpleButton_root ButtonOverrides_root'][.='Continue']"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the element with text as **Continue** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.primary.LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton.SimpleButton_root.ButtonOverrides_root[label='Continue']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='primary LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton SimpleButton_root ButtonOverrides_root' and text()='Continue']")
  ```

---

Ideally, to identify the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.primary.LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton.SimpleButton_root.ButtonOverrides_root[label='Continue']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='primary LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton SimpleButton_root ButtonOverrides_root' and text()='Continue']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't take all name do this:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton")
```

Verified if `LanguageSelectionForm_submitButton` is unique in document but if is not unique complete condition by using label="continue"

Thank you